# scrartcl without author?

Tags: koma-script, letters, article, report

I want to write a cost estimation for my part of a large business proposal, and I just tried `scrartcl`. My address I put in the top left corner using `\titlehead`. As it already contains my name, I did not specify `\author`. Now there is a gap between the title and the date.

Is it possible to reduce that gap? Should I better use another class?

I also considered `scrlttr2`, but it doesn't seem appropriate either: There is only my address, i.e. no destination address.

Example:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\title{Cost estimation}
% \author{}
\titlehead{Name\\Street\\City\\VATIN}
\date{11.10.2013}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Milestones}
Description
\section{Cost}
Estimation
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could for example write `\date{\vspace{-1cm}11.10.2013}` and adjust the space as you like it.